# With an extra flimsy cable length, the pump works...?

Tags: current, resistance, automotive, source

I have a 12V mattress pump that plugs into the car lighter socket.

One day I had the need to use it in the house, so the first time, in the urge, I grab an old 12V adapter, strip the cables of the pump, use some crocodile connectors to hook it to the adapter and here we go, mattress inflated

A little later I replaced the temporary crocodile connections with a clean pair of male/female jack connectors.
When pluging the circuit, the pump goes into intermittent bursts. As if the current was discontinued

So to recap:

12V TO flimsy crocodile cable TO pump => The pump works perfectly
[image: working montage]

12V DIRECTLY TO pump => The pump goes into intermittent bursts / disfunctional
[image: disfunctional montage]

I even made a video to showcase the issue - https://youtu.be/s5DjFHVJ2PU

I need help to understand and hopefully fix it!

I've been asking around, few handy mates, and even the electrical shop, 3 dudes there, no-one has been able to give me a lead...
They tried to replace the cable with resistances and capacitors but in vain.

Myself I tried different amperage of adapters, 1.5A, 2A & 3.5A. The result is a less powerful bursting mode with faster frequency of bursts on a lower aperage (see video).

In the despair, I've embedded the crocodile cable in the montage (shameless!), but at next use it did melt at the base of the crocodile jaw.
[image: messy montage][image: melted connection]

Idea ideas?
Happy to try multiple montage or measure anything to help figure it out.
I want to understand.

EDIT: On a demand, I tried to connect the small section of cable without the connectors (crocs) and the small copper thread are burning live, but the engine run perfectly! - https://youtu.be/WqIXVPMBFFg

Comment: Current on motor startup is much higher than when running continuously. The crocodile clamp probably works because its resistance reduces the startup current. The difference between a resistor and the clamp may be that clamp is more temperature-dependent, so as it heats up because of high current, the resistance increases to more than when measured normally.

Comment: It may be best to get a small car battery or UPS battery for home use.

Comment: Thanks for this comment @JiříMaier but surely there is a way to reproduce the comportment I get from the extra cable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a 12V mattress pump

These need a surprising amount of *amps* in order to run properly. No, 3.5A won't be enough. The lighter socket in a car has amps in the 8A-10A range typically.

You try using an old AT or ATX PC PSU, these have >10A on 12V.

Edit: The crocodile clips work as a series resistor that lowers the current enough keepigng the overcurrent protection from triggering inside those wall warts.

Comment: Your response reads super legit  I'll work on finding something with a much higher amperage to try indeed.
But since I can make it run with a piece of extra cable, how can I reproduce that with a component? A series of resistors? Which capacity?

Comment: That would be hard to determine, because the wall-wart "hiccup" current-limiting mode is dependent on many factors. You could try something like a 2Ω 10W resistor, but it will get *hot*. Best solution is to get a bigger power supply which will not hiccup.

Comment: I finally got my hands on an old ATX power supply and it works like a charm. Thanks @turbo-j